# Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I'm just simply run composer update command and than my hole project is stop and show the

```
Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found
```

I tried to run many command but not work.

like-
composer update --no-scripts
composer install
composer dump-autoload

Please help.

Comment: What did you change in your `composer.json` before you ran `composer update`? Try rolling back that change.

Comment: With out changes i run update command. I'm not doing any changes.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, delete `composer.lock` and the `vendor` folder and run the command `composer install`.

If you added to your `composer.json` dependencies, please delete this, because can be the cause of the error.

Comment: Just follow the procedure described above